# Force destroy process on port 80

Tags: apache-http-server, http, localhost, httpd

This might be a shot in the dark but I'll try anyway.

I require to run an app on `localhost:80` but found that it was blocked. When going to `localhost`, I was greeted with this:

[image]

Clearly this was something I thought up when playing around with java servlets.

More to the point, when checking processes that are running on `:80`, I am only greeted with `httpd` processes. When looking at all my current active processes in ActivityMonitor, there is nothing that strikes me as unusual. I have also recursively searched for the text "It works!" throughout the machine and nothing pops up *(I have also conducted other searches but found nothing)*. This servlet appears to be running at startup and have checked all startup menus that I am aware of and, again, nothing strikes me as out of place.

It seems like a process is running but the file that runs that process is gone, which I know is impossible.

My question is, is there a was to force terminate anything that is running on `:80`? *(highly unlikely as I've mentioned that it doesn't appear in any processes)*. Also, is there somehow a more recursive search I can do? I have done the basic `grep` search and an SSD search in Finder but both turn up nothing...

Comment: What's your question; Your screenshot clealry shows localhost:80 isn't blocked.  You have Apache installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it already pointed, "It works!" is text from default web page for Apache web server installed on your system. You can verify it yourself by running: `sudo lsof -n -iTCP:80 | grep LISTEN`. Finder usually won't to show content of `/etc` folder, so you need to click on *Go menu* (when in Finder), and choose `Go to Folder` where manually enter `/etc/apache2`. There you can spot apache's configuration files where you can find web directory under "DocumentRoot" stanza then if you will go to that location, you will find `index.html` file that contain "It works!"

If running Apache instance prevent to run you servlet on port 80 (which is obviously conflict), then change default Apache's port 80  to something different, say port 8080 and restart Apache service from terminal; `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! I knew `httpd` was an Apache instance but whenever I tried to kill the process via terminal *(`sudo kill -9 <PID>`)*, it would always just instantly restart

Answer (score 0):

The following command would stop the `apachectl` running process and free the port 80.

```
   sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
```